# Titanium Paypal Live Integration Issues in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, paypal, titanium-modules

I worked on paypal sandbox account it worked fine. But now i m moving on Live paypal so butt my paypal Button disabled and error shows on log is "You do not have a valid PayPal issued app ID". How can i get valid PayPal issued app ID? And the 2nd thing what is `"recipient"` and `"customID"` in PayPal? Which changes make my button enable. Thank you

My PayPal account Button code is

```
    var continueButton = Paypal.createPaypalButton({
    // NOTE: height/width only determine the size of the view that the button is embedded in - the actual button size
    // is determined by the buttonStyle property!
    width: 194 + u, height: 37 + u,
    //buttonStyle: Paypal.BUTTON_194x37, // The style & size of the button
    bottom:60,
    left : 84,

    language: 'en_US',
    //textStyle: PAYPAL_TEXT_PAY, // Causes the button's text to change from "Pay" to "Donate"

    appID: 'APP-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // The appID issued by Paypal for your application; for testing, feel free to delete this property entirely.
    paypalEnvironment: Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_LIVE, // Sandbox, None or Live .. For Device Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_NONE

    visible:false,

    feePaidByReceiver: false,
    enableShipping: false, // Whether or not to select/send shipping information

    payment: { // The payment itself
        //paymentType: Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, // The type of payment
        subtotal: 25, // The total cost of the order, excluding tax and shipping
        tax: 0,
        shipping: 0,
        currency: 'USD',
        recipient: 'recipient email address',
        customID: 'anythingYouWant',
        invoiceItems: [
            { name: 'My App', totalPrice: amnt1, itemPrice: amnt1, itemCount: 1 },

        ],

        merchantName: 'My App',
        memo: 'For My App'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using PayPal you send money to account using its email as an ID. So "recipient" is the email of the receiver. The "customID" is an ID that you choose to associate with the transaction. For the appID use this article. Aand good luck!
[PayPal Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#credentials)